# Autolinker string is wrongly splitting file path on white space when linking to a file

Tags: javascript, html

The following given variable is located in a function, within a script, within the body of an html file:

```
var popupContent = '<tr><td colspan="2">' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['filepath'])) + '</td></tr>;
```

I was trying to change it in order to link to a file, and changed it accordingly:

```
 var popupContent = '<tr><td colspan="2">'+ '<a href=' + Autolinker.link(String(feature.properties['filepath'])) + '>Check it out!</a>' + '</td></tr>';
```

The issue is that the latter is splitting the filepath on the first white space that it meets. Is there a way to rewrite this variable in order to also include the space?

An example of the output link is `\\srv\Ex Ample\link\image.jpg` in the first case, and `\\srv\Ex` in the second case, by clicking on the created link.

Comment: Hi can you share an example file path case which would be problematic. The Autolinker generates an a href may be you need to use the Html tag builder: http://gregjacobs.github.io/Autolinker.js/docs/#!/api/Autolinker.HtmlTag

Comment: Just posted an example of the file path. I will check the link you sent me as well, but I think it is used just for an http link, right?

Comment: To my knowledge this seems that you can build whatever link you want. It gives you none of the match functionality to determine what source is the link. Why don't you simply put the filepath in the href without any Autolinker functionality?